# QGIS creates BOX with no data when merged

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, nodata, gdal-merge

I have 2 rasters. The first one is a lidar which is clipped by a masked layer. (30.53mb, pixel size=1m,float32)

[image]

The other is a local survey GEOTIFF. (75kb, pixel size=1m,float32)

[image]

When I merge them, QGIS makes a "box" with no data values. This is the command:

GDAL command:
gdal_merge.bat -a_nodata 0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mciOFb/1182dffdfdad4287b941faacdf067b43/OUTPUT.tif --optfile C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mciOFb/268a4fe4705745a6817ebfd45e67ff3b/mergeInputFiles.txt

[image]

What am I missing?

I have done these things for many times and my first time to experience this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smaller raster was an output from the Raster Calculator and was not showing the correct extents (showing only positive results). The Raster Calculator produced a box/rectangular raster (including negative results).

This is the reason why there is a box when I merged the two rasters as it included the areas with negative values.